# Tweepy API: add tags / mentions to attached photo

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have created a twitter bot using the Tweepy API. It works great, it tweets a tweet with a photo attached to it. However, I would like to add "mentions" or "In this photo"  @accounts (tags) to the attached image. This is possible on twitter. I have red the Tweepy documentation and searched online, looking for a parameter but I could not find anything. Any suggestion would appriciated!

code snippet:

```
api = tweepy.API(oauth)

api.update_with_media(filename='screenshot.png', status=masterStatus)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please do not use `update_with_media`, as this is a deprecated API. It works for now, but will get no support. The current correct route is the two-step use of `media_upload`, followed by `update_status` (you can also add image alt text using `create_media_metadata` in between those two steps, if you like). The Tweepy 3.9.0 documentation mentions this.

For the main part of the question - the Twitter API itself does not currently support adding people tags to images, so this is also unavailable in Tweepy. If you would like to request this feature in a future version of the Twitter API, you can do so [here](https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com/).